# Electron as system service with ELECTRON_RUN_AS_NODE

Tags: electron, electron-builder

What is The Correct(tm) way for an Electron application to run both as a desktop application and as a service?

I have looked high and low for this but to no avail. This is how I think it should work.

Create a launchd/systemd/windows service description that:

1. Sets ELECTRON_RUN_AS_NODE environment variable
2. Runs the packaged Electron application
3. Produces happiness?

Can the packaged Electron application run in this manner access the contents of the ASAR file? If it can, great.

Then just build and package two directories with the application. Both compiled for the ABI version Electron is on:

1. Directory electron_modules with binary modules compiled for an executable that reports being electron
2. Directory node_modules with binary modules compiled for an executable that reports being node

With the appropriate NODE_PATH also set in the service description, I should be all golden.

Right?

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure what the OP is asking but I found this question while looking for: how do I run an Electron application as a desktop application and also as a CLI service with no access to a display driver?

The answer [from here](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/testing-on-headless-ci) is

> Being based on Chromium, Electron requires a display driver to function. If Chromium can't find a display driver, Electron will fail to launch ... **In essence, we need to use a virtual display driver**.

The solution (on linux at least)

1. Install `xvfb`
2. Prefix your start command with `xvfb-run` e.g. `xvfb-run node_modules/electron/dist/electron .`